# Installing TFS 2012 on win 2003 server

Tags: tfs, windows-2003-webserver

Our company just bought this TFS2012 . Our server is windows 2003 R2 Enterprise edition. When i tried to install it on the server I am getting following error:

One or more system check failed:

Error : TF400154 : Installation on this version of Windows is not supported.

Any work around for this to install on my windows 2003 server.Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* workaround is to upgrade the server.

TFS2012 server requirements are at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically, it requires IIS 7 (or later).  Which you can't install on a 2003 server.  It comes with 2008.  Even then, it has to be the 64 bit version of windows.

If you are upgrading I'd recommend a minimum of 2008 R2; that only comes in a 64 bit flavor.

Comment: How about TFs 2010 on windows 2003? Do you know that Microsoft can down grade my key to applicable to TFS 2010 from TFS 2013?

Comment: I highly suggest you review the requirements link I posted; it's good practice to be able to read that stuff so you don't get in this situation again.  There is an option to view the requirements for "other versions" including 2010.  For your second answer, MS is the only one that can answer you: call them.